# Get item in dask array by one index in another dask array

Tags: python, dask

`A` and `B` are two dask arrays. `B` only contains a single integer.
How to find `A[B]`?

The following code seems to work. Is there a better way?

```
import dask.array as da
from dask import delayed
import numpy as np
idx = da.from_array(np.array([0]), 1) + 10
y = da.arange(12, chunks = 2)
idx2 = delayed(np.ravel)(idx)
z = delayed(da.take)(y, idx2)
print(z)
print(z.compute())
```

Comment: probably this is not using the threaded scheduler.

Comment: Doesn't really work. shape/chunks are lost after using `delayed`, even if I use the `nout` keyword of `delayed`. I guess I have to write a custom function over dask graph.

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to do in general because any element in B may refer to any element in A.  I don't see any way to make this computationally efficient.  If B is small then you could convert it into a numpy array, and then this would work fine.  If B is not fine then you're trying to do something that is very very hard.

It may be that the shuffling algorithms in dask.dataframe could help you if your problem fits that data model.  This would look more like a dataframe join.

Comment: I tried converting B to a numpy array, but that didn't work for me because I want lazy evaluation for B.